# Managing Email Pages

Tags: publishing, dxa, outbound-email, sdl-tridion

We are running SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and DXA 1.0 (Java). In a DXA based CMS/website how would the pages used for Outbound Email mailings be managed? We have created standard Outbound Email TBBs to manage the pages in the CMS however we are having difficulty publishing/resolving images referenced in those pages. We would like to have the images (used in email communication) referenced from the website.

Can someone shed some light on how to get these images published and the URL resolved when accessing the email?

Comment: There is no (official) DXA 1.0 Java release. You are probably using a pre-release version. I would recommend to upgrade to the first official public release: DXA 1.2 Java.

Comment: @Rick I know we are using a pre-release build, however we currently do not have the luxury of time to upgrade to the latest release (1.2) since as you might also be aware that the upgrade from 1.0 to 1.2 is not straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Outbound Email is a solution which is based on the Modular Templating model using DWT Templating Building Blocks for the layout of your email. So if we are just talking about generating a mailing you can simply follow the [documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-80D2FDE4-C3F7-4FD0-B77B-8AD37E0671DA), and that is completely disconnected/separate from your DXA implementation (even though it can be in the same Publication).

But if you would want to reuse that same mailing Page to provide a web version of your email, then you can't really use the existing TBBs or Dreamweaver layout, since that would publish either ASPX or JSP, which does not work with the DXA MVC web application.

There currently is no DXA module with support for Outbound Email, which basically means you will have to do the ground work for this yourself. You will simply need to generate a view for your mailing and render the content from the mailing like you do with any other content on the DXA implementation.

Comment: Thanks Bart for your response. At the moment we would simply like to be able to manage email pages and mailings using the standard OE TBBs Actually we have already created the TBBs and compound templates and published a page that we want to use for the mailing.  However any images that are referenced in the page are not being published and do not show up in the email. Even if we somehow get those images to publish the DXA web application does not serve such images outside the MVC framework.

Comment: @hzahid It's been a while since I did an OE implementation, so my knowledge on it is a bit rusty. But I think you should consider using a different publication target for your mailing, so that the images end up in a different location/web application, You should not publish them to the DXA target, since then everything goes into the broker, and that is not want you need in this case. You need to keep DXA and the mailing separated, as one is MVC and the other not. Or embed the images in the email, rather than publishing them out to a server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of having a separate publishing target for publishing Outbound Email related contents. We will implement accordingly.